# Gradle run keeps returning exit value 1

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I am developing a javafx application and both `gradle wrapper`and `gradle build` finish successfully. Unfortunately, when I try to do `gradle run`, I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong: 
Execution failed for task ':run'. 
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I understand it might be related to the jfxrt.jar. Am I missing an import?

```
gradle -v 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Gradle 2.6 
------------------------------------------------------------ 

Build time:   2015-08-10 13:15:06 UTC 
Build number: none 
Revision:     233bbf8e47c82f72cb898b3e0a96b85d0aad166e 

Groovy:       2.3.10 
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013 
JVM:          1.8.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 25.51-b03) 
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.4 x86_64
```

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
apply plugin: 'eclipse' 
apply plugin: 'application' 

mainClassName = 'main.screens.ScreenFramework' 

jar { 
    baseName = 'wfmgrG' 
    version =  '0.1.0' 
} 

sourceCompatibility = 1.7 
targetCompatibility = 1.7 


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { 
    gradleVersion = '2.3' 
}
```

When running `gradle run --debug 2> gradlebug.txt`, this is my gradlebug.txt file:

```
14:32:57.310 [ERROR] [system.err] Exception in Application start method 
14:32:57.331 [ERROR] [system.err] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
14:32:57.332 [ERROR] [system.err]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
14:32:57.333 [ERROR] [system.err]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
14:32:57.333 [ERROR] [system.err]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
14:32:57.333 [ERROR] [system.err]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
14:32:57.333 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389) 
14:32:57.333 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328) 
14:32:57.333 [ERROR] [system.err]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
14:32:57.334 [ERROR] [system.err]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
14:32:57.334 [ERROR] [system.err]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
14:32:57.334 [ERROR] [system.err]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
14:32:57.335 [ERROR] [system.err]         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767) 
14:32:57.335 [ERROR] [system.err] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method 
14:32:57.336 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917) 
14:32:57.336 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182) 
14:32:57.337 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1323468230.run(Unknown Source) 
14:32:57.337 [ERROR] [system.err]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
14:32:57.338 [ERROR] [system.err] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
14:32:57.338 [ERROR] [system.err]         at main.java.screens.ScreenFramework.start(ScreenFramework.java:39) 
14:32:57.338 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863) 
14:32:57.339 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/292202963.run(Unknown Source) 
14:32:57.339 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326) 
14:32:57.339 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/186276003.run(Unknown Source) 
14:32:57.339 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295) 
14:32:57.339 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/963494156.run(Unknown Source) 
14:32:57.339 [ERROR] [system.err]         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
14:32:57.340 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294) 
14:32:57.341 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/237061348.run(Unknown Source) 
14:32:57.342 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95) 
14:32:57.342 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) 
14:32:57.342 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101) 
14:32:57.342 [ERROR] [system.err]         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source) 
14:32:57.343 [ERROR] [system.err]         ... 1 more 
14:32:57.348 [ERROR] [system.err] Exception running application main.java.screens.ScreenFramework 
14:32:57.708 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:32:57.708 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
14:32:57.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:32:57.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong: 
14:32:57.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':run'. 
14:32:57.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Process 'command 'C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 
14:32:57.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:32:57.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try: 
14:32:57.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

The debug stack trace was too long to post here.

Comment: Could you please run the task with `-d` (debug) switch? It will be easier to solve the problem.

Comment: You're right, @Opal ! Right now I'm not able to do it but I will edit my question later with that information.

Comment: added error trace @Opal

Comment: there's an NPE being thrown. Verify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ScreenFramework class at line no 39.  This is caused by java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
14:32:57.338 [ERROR] [system.err] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
14:32:57.338 [ERROR] [system.err]         at main.java.screens.ScreenFramework.start(ScreenFramework.java:39)
```

Comment: I did but it's working fine. It runs without problems both in the eclipse environment and after I extract the jar.

Comment: Do you have any runtime libraries? It seems when running using Gradle some fields are not initialized.